# How to make UNIX "set" command print only environment variables

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am used to the bash `set` command listing only a list of the environment settings, eg. PATH and such.

However, on an Ubuntu system I just set up, executing `set` dumps 2000 lines of text, including lots of functions like this:

```
dequote () 
{ 
    eval printf %s "$1" 2> /dev/null
}
```

How do I print only the environment variables?

Comment: Note that your Ubuntu system almost certainly is using bash as well - it's the default on new installs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `set` shows the *shell variables*, not just the environment variables. In `bash` functions are considered part of the variables. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference .

If you use `env` or `printenv` they will show the *environment* exported to child processes, which is not *necessarily* the same as your `bash` environment:

```
$ foo=1
$ printenv foo
$ export foo
$ printenv foo
1
```

The bash `declare` and `typeset` builtins can list all types of variables, to omit functions:

```
declare -F
```

The output of these is in a form suitable for recreating the state in a shell script, so it's a little verbose, though you can distinguish between arrays, integers and other types (depending on version). See also the output of `export -p`.

And from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305237/how-to-list-variables-declared-in-script-in-bash
you can tell bash to use POSIX mode, and `set` behaves "properly":

```
( set -o posix ; set )
```

That's run in a subshell so it doesn't alter your running shell, and it correctly picks up variables not yet exported into the inherited environment.

Comment: I found it useful to add an alias in `.bashrc` so I have a `realset` command, and thus don't have to remember the subshell incantation: `alias realset='( set -o posix ; set )'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all the environment variables, simply enter `env`.